# Python: string concatenation with None to return None?

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements, concatenation

I'm trying to do a conditional assignment based on the return value for environmental variables.

```
self._TBLFilePath = iTBLFilePath or os.environ.get("CDO_TBLPATH") + os.environ.get("CDO_INSTANCE_TYPE") + ".tbl" or os.environ.ge    t("CDO_ROOT") + "/cdo/tbl/" + os.environ.get("CDO_INSTANCE_TYPE") + ".tbl"
```

The problem is when CDO_TBLPATH is undefined I get a string with None concatenation error. I wonder if there is a way to force None + string to return a None as well, or is there any other way to overcome this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[`mapping.get()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) supports a 'default' argument:

```
os.environ.get("CDO_TBLPATH", '')
```

The default is to return `None`, but by specifying an empty string your concatenation will work even if `CDO_TBLPATH` is not defined.

You cannot have the concatenation magically return `None` if the `.get()` return None; you could use a custom class that returns `None` in a `__add__` method but I'm not sure if that'd be very readable.

If you need to skip any of the options (not concatenate) if the environment variable is not defined, you'd be better off splitting out the tests:

```
table_options = (
    (lambda: iTBLFilePath, lambda: iTBLFilePath)
    (lambda: os.environ.get("CDO_TBLPATH") and os.environ.get("CDO_INSTANCE_TYPE"),
        lambda: os.environ["CDO_TBLPATH"] + os.environ["CDO_INSTANCE_TYPE"] + '.tbl'),
    (lambda: os.environ.get("CDO_ROOT") and os.environ.get("CDO_INSTANCE_TYPE"),
        lambda: os.environ["CDO_ROOT"] + "/cdo/tbl/" + os.environ["CDO_INSTANCE_TYPE"] + ".tbl"),
    (lambda: True, lambda: None),
)

self. _TBLFilePath = next(opt() for tst, opt in table_options if tst())
```

This defines a series of tests, and the value associated with the first test that is successful is used.

Comment: Sorry, if my question was a bit confusing. What I actually want to achieve is that the second operand (os.environ.get("CDO_TBLPATH") + os.environ.get("CDO_INSTANCE_TYPE") + ".tbl") would return False/None in case one of those env variables is not set

Answer (score 0):

For this, I sometimes borrow the `coalesce()` function from SQL. In Python, it works this way:

```
coalesce = lambda *a: next((i for i in a if i is not None), None)
```

or maybe better

```
def coalesce(*a):
    """Return the first non-`None` argument, or `None` if there is none."""
    return next((i for i in a if i is not None), None)
```

It returns the first non-`None` argument, or `None` if there is none.

If there was no default argument for `.get()`, you could do

```
coalesce(get('...'), '')
```